# Mysql Create table with best method

Tags: mysql

- I have customer table
- I have article table
- I have Distribution article table

I want to send 1 article to all the customers. In distribution table. Now we are adding duplicate rows for each article with customer id.

How can we avoid this, If we make Customers as column, New customer added always we need to alter the Distribution table.

Comment: why do you want to avoid that? sounds correct to me. `customer(id, name, ...), article(id, text, ...), distribution(customer_id, article_id, date_sent, ...)`

Comment: Thanks for the replay, Same article I am sending to many customers, duplicate the article details. Is there any other way to do.

Comment: you're not duplicating the article details, you're just using the article id to reference the article in another table. this is the correct way to do it

Comment: Make a many-to-many table.